# Python declaring file object but not opening a file

Tags: python, file

I am writing a Python program where I need to write to a file.  I need an if condition to determine if I need to keep writing to same file or open a new file.  How do I declare the file so that I can access it with both the if and else?  Right now I'm making a test file before the loop just so I have access to the variable.  How to avoid opening a TEST.txt file while still having a variable f that I can operate on?

```
f = open(outputFolder + "TEST.txt", 'w') # how to avoid opening TEST.txt here
while row: 
    #print(str(row[0]) + '|' + str(row[4]))
    currentFileName = getFileName(str(row[0])) 
    # If coming up on new date open new file
    if currentFileName != fileName:
        f.close()
        fileName = currentFileName
        print("Processing: " + fileName)
        f = open(outputFolder + fileName, 'w')
        f.write(getLine(row))

    # else write to current file
    else:
        f.write(getLine(row))
    row = cursor.fetchone()
```

Comment: @RandomDavis I have a extra TEST.txt that I'm not using after the program runs

Comment: Never mind my last comment. What is `f` supposed to be by the time you reach the `else` condition? If it's a file you have to write to, but you didn't open a new one in the `if` block, what value do you want it to have beforehand? You could always declare `f = None` or something like that before the loop, but then if you tried to do `f.write` that would give an error. Do you maybe just need to put `if f is not None` in your `else` statement to avoid trying to do operations on it if it's not set? But it's not obvious, and you haven't explained, what it should be set to at that point.

Comment: @RandomDavis the file will always be open by the time it reaches the else.  I just want both the if and else to access the f variable without having to open a TEST.txt file if that makes sense.

Comment: I'll wait until you've clarified the problem.  Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't work out your logic before writing the program.  What you describe in words does not match what you wrote.  Start with the words, draw a flowchart, and *then* write your code.

In your posted program, you're trying to open `currentFile` multiple times, you don't initialize or change `row`, and it's not clear what you intend the program to do.

```
if [condition]:
    filename = currentFileName
else:
    filename = "TEST.txt"

f = open(filename)

for ... # whatever you're trying to do with your input and output,
        # look up the proper method in a file-handling tutorial.
```

Comment: I was trying to simplify my code see edit